# mybatis update is not working

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

I'm using mybatis for the update and query doesn't update the table: can any one help me whats going wrong

configuration

```
    <update id="updateInfo" parameterType="int" timeout="20">
        UPDATE RULE_DETAILS
        SET state=0
        WHERE severity ='info'
        and cfg_id=#{cfg_id}   
    </update
```

calling

```
session.selectList("updateInfo",  cfg_id);
```

and log also shows

```
DEBUG java.sql.PreparedStatement - ==>  Executing: UPDATE RULE_DETAILS SET state=0 WHERE severity ='warning' and cfg_id=? 

DEBUG java.sql.PreparedStatement - ==> Parameters: 2572(Integer)
```

but database is not updated with this data. can any one please help me..

Comment: Make sure you are committing your update. Are you facing a problem only with this SQL? Can you do a simple select or insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use session.update() but not session.selectList().